# Automate a manual process of opening / saving as files

Tags: windows, file, command

I have a tool which opens `.HED` files which are some kind of documents created a long time ago..

This type of files is so old and tools opening this extensions are rare. fortunately, I have a tool which opens them. when opened this program gives the choice to open files and saving them as other extensions (`.rtf` for example )

The problem is: there are about 400 files to be converted from `.rtf` to `.hed` and we went to automate this process of opening `.rtf` file saving it as `.hed` by some command line.

Is there a way to do so in Windows?

I'm able to open the program by "open 'program_name'" but I'm wondering if it's possible to open all files in folder and saving them as `.hed` after

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  Would you please share the tool that you have that will open the .HED documents?  Please let me know.

Comment: Hello, we are still creating the rtf files and converting them to HED. the tool we use for opening .HED files is hepro32.. if you didnt find it online let me know so i can send it to you

Comment: I need to go from HED to RTF.  Will this hepro32 app do that?  if so, would you please put it somewhere I can download? When I search on it all I get is a bunch of advertising sites that have no real download.  thank you!

Comment: Hey dave i'm at work now.. when i'll get some time i'll load in some hosting website and send you link have a nice day

Comment: Can you send me an email at slacker_home@yahoo.com?

Comment: hello dave gmail is not allowing me to send you the executable even when its zipped. do you have an idea how i can send you the program ? thank you

Comment: send me an email and I will write you back with a way to send the file to me.